# SSL client hello reset

Tags: security, ssl, iis, https, tls1.2

Ι have an IoT device posting data to a web app hosted to IIS 6.2.
Posting with http is working perfectly. When i change it to https i am getting handshake error.

The same web app has web interface that uses the same SSL certificate and works perfectly on all browsers. Thus I guess, that SSL setup is correct.

I have tried to change the server certificate with a self signed certificate create from IIS with the same results.

I have also tested the IoT device to other servers with SSL and it works.

Here is the wireshark communication

[image]

and here are the SSL protocols available on server

[image]
[image]

i am also attaching a report from ssllabs

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Have you changed the default port or the server is still listening to the 443 port?

Comment: It is listening to the default port 443.

Comment: "The same web app has web interface that uses the same SSL certificate and works perfectly on all browsers." Capture packets using Wireshark when you use such a browser and compare the handshake packets.

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Could you share some logs and more details about the application and they system it's running on?
Can it be because your client (perhaps a java program or something else) doesn't have a properly configurated certificate store?

Comment: The IoT device has a Telit modem handled with AT commands. It responses error 839 Handshake error.